# Git bash localhost:8080 : Connection refused error

Tags: java, spring, bash, spring-boot, git-bash

I'm very new to using git bash, and was going through the Spring Boot tutorial, given here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

I tried executing:

```
    curl localhost:8080
```

But received the following message:

```
    $ curl localhost:8080

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

I've tried doing this to fix this, but no luck:

```
    # Get system value
    $ git config --system --get https.proxy
    $ git config --system --get http.proxy

    # Get global value
    $ git config --global --get https.proxy
    $ git config --global --get http.proxy

    # Check configuration for your user
    $ cat $HOME/.gitconfig

    # Unset system value
    $ git config --system --unset https.proxy
    $ git config --system --unset http.proxy

    # Unset global value
    $ git config --global --unset https.proxy
    $ git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? (Please simplify the steps if possible, I started using git really recently! :) )

Comment: `git config --system --get https.proxy` unsets proxy only for git commands. `curl`is a regular bash command.

Comment: connection refused means the port is closed.

Comment: Are you running a web server on port 8080?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've managed to create a rule for 8080 in my Inbound Rules on my Firewall, but it's still not connecting, and when I type 'netstat -an' , I can't see the port in the Local address column